# Unique Combination of Set

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to write vb.net code to return unique combinations for set 
My set contains 3 different elements. I've found similar post this Post but couldn't find any VB solution to get this results

Example:

Elements: 1, 2, 3

> { 1, 2, 3}
>
> Result must be

```
1
2
3
12
13
23
123
...........
>...................
```

i,m trying to achieve this by using following code

```
Function GetCombinations(ByVal depth As Integer, ByVal values As String()) As IEnumerable(Of String)
    If depth > values.Count + 1 Then Return New List(Of String)
    Dim result = New List(Of String)

    For i = 0 To depth - 1
        For y = 0 To values.Count - 1
            If i = 0 Then
                result.Add(values(y))
            Else
                result.Add(values(i - 1) + values(y))
            End If
        Next
    Next
    Return result
End Function
```

To Get the result

```
Dim reslt = GetCombinations(4, data_array)

?reslt
Count = 12
    (0): "1"
    (1): "2"
    (2): "3"
    (3): "11"
    (4): "12"
    (5): "13"
    (6): "21"
    (7): "22"
    (8): "23"
    (9): "31"
    (10): "32"
    (11): "33"
```

Hint:
I work with Mathematics and manage to calculate no of combinations. i can test the out with 
this formula

Example
there is this formula called nCr. it means out of n number of element how many way of taking r number of elements with unique combinations of r.

```
nPr = n!/(n-r)!
n! = 1 * 2 * 3 * 4* ... (n-1) * n

Elements: 1, 2, 3
In this case n = 3 and r can be 1, 2, and 3 all

number of combinations  = 3P1 + 3P2 + 3P3
                                          = 3!/2! + 3!/1! + 3!/0!
                                          = 6/2 + 6/1 + 6/1                    (0!=1)
                                          = 3+6+6
                                          = 15
```

Comment: Does the output have to be ordered like in your sample output?

Comment: Please show what code you have written to attempt this. Helping you is only fruitful when you have invested time in coding a solution.

Comment: Here's a hint. Write out the integers from 0 to 7 in binary: 000, 001, 010, 011, 100, 101, 110, 111. Now in each, multiply the low binary digit by the first number, the second binary digit by the second number, and the high binary digit by the third number. That's 000, 001, 020, 021, 300, 301, 320, 321.  Now do you see how this process enables you to obtain your solution?

Comment: Az Za- I've Edited, to add the Code

Comment: Are 1,3 and 3,1 different combinations?

Comment: 1,3 and 3,1 are typically regarded as different *permutations* of the same *combination*.

Comment: dbsentt--> 1,3 and 3,1 are same.,

Answer (score 1):

Knowing the term makes it easier to find existing algorithms. What you're looking for is a **power set**. Here's a quick VB.NET translation of a C# implementation I found on [Rosetta Code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Power_set):

```
Public Function GetPowerSet(Of T)(ByVal input As IEnumerable(Of T)) As IEnumerable(Of IEnumerable(Of T))
    Dim seed As IEnumerable(Of IEnumerable(Of T)) = {Enumerable.Empty(Of T)()}
    Return input.Aggregate(seed, Function(a, b) a.Concat(a.Select(Function(x) x.Concat({b}))))
End Function
```

Testing:

```
For Each x In GetPowerSet({1, 2, 3})
    Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", x))
Next
```

Output:

```
1
2
1, 2
3
1, 3
2, 3
1, 2, 3
```

**EDIT** - Based on your latest explanation, I think you need a different approach. It seems you want [combinations with repetitions / replacement](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Combinations_with_repetitions), for all sizes up to the input size. You could simply call one of those algorithms with parameters *(S, k)* for each value of *k* from 1 to *n* and join all the results into a single set of results.

Translating [Python's algorithm](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations_with_replacement):

```
Public Iterator Function GetCombinationsWithReplacement(Of T)(source As IEnumerable(Of T), size As Integer) As IEnumerable(Of IEnumerable(Of T))
    Dim pool = source.ToList()
    Dim n = pool.Count
    If n = 0 AndAlso size > 0 Then
        Return
    End If
    Dim indices = Enumerable.Repeat(0, size).ToList()
    Yield indices.Select(Function(i) pool.Item(i))
    While True
        Dim index As Nullable(Of Integer) = Nothing
        For i = size - 1 To 0 Step -1
            If indices.Item(i) <> n - 1 Then
                index = i
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        If Not index.HasValue Then
            Return
        End If
        indices = indices.Take(index.Value).Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(indices.Item(index.Value) + 1, size - index.Value)).ToList()
        Yield indices.Select(Function(i) pool.Item(i))
    End While
End Function
```

(You will need to modify this if your VB.NET compiler doesn't support [Yield](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh156729.aspx).)

The results of calling this with different sizes are:

`GetCombinationsWithReplacement({1, 2, 3}, 1)`:

```
{1}
{2}
{3}
```

`GetCombinationsWithReplacement({1, 2, 3}, 2)`:

```
{1, 1}
{1, 2}
{1, 3}
{2, 2}
{2, 3}
{3, 3}
```

`GetCombinationsWithReplacement({1, 2, 3}, 3)`:

```
{1, 1, 1}
{1, 1, 2}
{1, 1, 3}
{1, 2, 2}
{1, 2, 3}
{1, 3, 3}
{2, 2, 2}
{2, 2, 3}
{2, 3, 3}
{3, 3, 3}
```

We can join these into a single sequence with all 19 subsets:

```
Public Iterator Function GetCombinationsWithReplacementAllSizes(Of T)(source As IEnumerable(Of T)) As IEnumerable(Of IEnumerable(Of T))
    Dim pool = source.ToList()
    For size = 1 To pool.Count
        For Each subset In GetCombinationsWithReplacement(pool, size)
            Yield subset
        Next
    Next
End Function
```

Comment: in theory Output must have 15 unique combinations but by using your code i got few numbers--> 121, 231, 32, 31, 2, 3

Comment: @user1403070 Well, in a comment on your post you said {1,3} and {3,1} are the same. If the same items in a different order should not be included, those 7 are the only outputs. Otherwise you want *permutations*.

Comment: I really appreciate it but still some unique combinations are missing {1,1},{2,2},{3,3},{1,1,1},{2,2,2},{3,3,3},{1,1,2},{1,1,3},{1,2,1},{1,3,1},{1,2,2}, i think its more than 15

Comment: @user1403070 I'm not sure what you want now, because including {1,1,3} and {1,3,1} seems to contradict your rule that {1,3} and {3,1} are the same. Also, your original question says *Set*, and a set by definition has no duplicates and no order -- in other words, all of these are considered the same set: {1,2}, {2,1}, {1,2,1}, {1,2,2}

Comment: You right its mistake on my previous comment. missing combinations are {1,1},{2,2},{3,3},{1,1,1},{2,2,2},{3,3,3},{1,1,2},{1,1,3}...Sorry about that.

Comment: @user1403070 Okay, I edited my answer with another solution. However it gives 19 results, not 15... so either the formula you posted was wrong, or this is still the wrong solution.

Comment: That's Great this's the output i looking for if i want to print that how do that this is my approach but its not working               ->>>>For Each subset In GetCombinationsWithReplacement({1, 2, 3}, 2)
     >>>> Debug.WriteLine(subset)
>>>>Next  I need to look back the formula apparently its wrong

Comment: @user1403070 For output you can use `String.Join(", ", combination)` like I'm doing in the test code for `GetPowerSet`. If you need to store the results in memory you can do `combination.ToList()`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some pseudo code for any number of elements to help you (I make no claim this is the fastest way to do this, it is just a way to do it.)

- Given elementList is a list of elements given
- Given tempList is a list as a temporary holder
- Given resultList is a list of the result

  ```
  loop by # items in elementlist
  {
    if tempList is empty  // special case for first iteration
      add each element of elementList to tempList and resultlist
    else
    {
      for each element in templist
        for each element2 in elementlist
          add combo to result list
      copy elements added to result list for this iteration to templist
    } 
  }
  ```