# Power Set Algorithm In VB.NET Is it Possible?

Tags: vb.net

I am making a program that user will input a set of elements example: "abcd"
and display an output {a}{b}{c}{a,b}{a,c}{b,c}

I know it is possible in C++ and java but i stopped when i got problems with VB.net

Is my method correct? Or should I go with for loops? Please help

This is my code so far

```
Public Class Form3

    Friend X As Integer

    Private Sub btnOK_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnOK.Click

        If txtelements.Text = String.Empty Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please Input an element")
        Else

            Dim i As Integer = 0

                X = txtelements.Text.Length
                If i > X Then
                    Dim Chars As Char() = txtelements.Text.ToCharArray()

                MessageBox.Show("{" & Chars(i) & "}")
                i = i + 1
            Else

            End If
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: VBA is a Turing-complete language, so Yes, it is possible.

Comment: Perhaps I haven't understood the requirements correctly. But to the question "is it possible to build an algorithm performing X actions?" The answer is usually the same one in all the languages: yes (, although might be impractically difficult), just build the algorithm. The differences between programming languages are usually in how easy/difficult is performing certain tasks and how efficient are similar implementations. But if you know how to build the algorithm, you would be able to do it in any language (and, logically, in VB.NET).

Comment: As far as you are claiming that you have built this algorithm in Java and C++, I guess that you are interested in performing a conversion to VB.NET. Please, show us any of these codes, such that we can advise you.

Comment: See nmclean's **first** answer (above the edit) [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18420477/2330053).

Comment: No wonder this doesn't work. You have this: `If i > X Then` where i is guaranteed to be 0 and X is guaranteed to 0 or greater. That condition will **never** be true.

Comment: Isn't this just a problem of producing all possible combinations? The required output is all possible combinations of a, b & c  assuming non repeating values upto a length of 2. I'd question why 'd' has been omitted?