# vb.net Get Unique sets of 2 digits from three digit variable, how to get Out Put in Textbox or listbox

Tags: vb.net, combinations

i need permutation and combination of 3 digits/characters  in pattern of two i mean i want to

```
{1, 1}
{1, 2}
{1, 3}
{2, 2}
{2, 3}
{3, 3}
```

out put from 1, 2, 3 input
i finded following code on the forum the link is 
[Unique Combination of Set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18384463/unique-combination-of-set)

by fallowing auther

https://stackoverflow.com/users/933416/nmclean

the problem is that when i call this function it shows error

```
GetCombinationsWithReplacement({1, 2, 3}, 2):
```

**Error is**

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll
```

i want to show results in textbox or listbox thanks in advance